# Can I conclude the following about limsup

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show that if $F:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and of bounded variation then $g(x)=\limsup_{h\rightarrow 0, h>0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$ is a Lebesgue measurable function.

Here's what I tried. WTS that for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we have the set $$\left\{x\in[a,b]|\limsup_{h\rightarrow 0, h>0} \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}<\alpha\right\}$$ is Lebesgue measurable. By definition of $\limsup$, the above says $$\left\{x\in[a,b]\;|\;\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}(\sup\{ \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}|h\in (0,\epsilon]\}) <\alpha\right\}$$ is Lebesgue measurable (1). I first show that for all $\epsilon$, the set $\{x\in[a,b]\;|\;\sup\{ \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}|h\in (0,\epsilon]\}<\alpha\}$ is measurable. Let $\{r_1,r_2\cdots\}=(0,\epsilon] \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Then $$\{x\in[a,b]\;|\;\sup\{ \frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}|h\in (0,\epsilon]\}<\alpha\}=\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{x\in[a,b]\;|\;\ \frac{F(x+r_n)-F(x)}{r_n}<\alpha\}.$$ Each set in LHS is measurable since $F$ is continuous, therefore measurable. Hence LHS is countable intersection of measurable sets, therefore measurable. To show (1), I just write use the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ of $\frac{1}{n}$ instead of $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I must admit to not checking every detail, but you definitely have the right approach.

Comment: I feel like the key step above, is the one where I set the set that doesnt involve rationals to the intersection of sets involving rationals. Does that step seem correct? I've spent a day thinking of this.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.  But you have to use the fact that $F$ is continuous.  Indeed, now that I look at your proof, it was an important omission in your proof.  You need to modify the proof and justify that step.  You will have to use the continuity of $F$ to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that, but as with several other details of the proof, I skipped in the above. I thought it would be already too boring that nobody would read it.

Comment: Fair enough.  But since you spent a day worrying about it, it is probably prudent to put that detail in.

Comment: Yeah, I should have. Thanks for your input.